# CMake how to determine the default C++ Standard?

Tags: cmake

I can set the variable `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` like this

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

but I can't print it like this

```
message("This is the C++ Standard we are using: ${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}")
```

I guess the variable `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` doesn't exist by default unless explicitly specified.

In such case, how is the default C++ Standard determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I guess the variable CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD doesn't exist by default unless explicitly specified.`

Correct. If you need a specific C++ version you should specify.

`In such case, how is the default C++ Standard determined?`

If you don't specify it depends on the compiler. As an example new versions of `MSVC` for example default to [C++14](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170). As they don't want to maintain `C++11` / `C++98`.

Not specifying the C++ standard is equivalent to not specifying other compiler flags. IE you are fine with the compiler provided defaults. Similar to how if you don't specify `RTTI` most C++ compilers will assume you want it enabled.

There are some projects that strive to work with whatever the compiler will give them, and a result won't specify the standard. This depends on what you want to support as a developer.

In most cases though it's a good idea to specify the C++ standard for your project.